# What's the proper way to let vb.net program to read a list?

Tags: vb.net

For example, say I have a vb.net program and I want the program to be able to reference country codes. If I know the country name I wants to know the country code and via versa.

I can hardcode all the country in the program.

I can make the program read a text file

What would be the proper way?

I am thinking of something like string table in ios programming where instead of telling what a label should say you make a table and then the code reference that table. Something like resource file? Does vb.net have that?

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you will have the data in a file in your hard drive instead of "hardcoded" ,
it will be easier to change, add, replace, delete values , not mention if you will suddenly decide to move to another country ;)

Comment: I can do that. But the text file won't be part of vb.net project files. Not like other codes.

Comment: why not? just create a text file in the project directory

Answer (score 1):

I would make an enumeration list.

i.e.

```
Public Enum CountryCodes
     Albania = 355
     Algeria = 213
     American Samoa= 684
End Enum
```

Find enum

```
Dim value As CountryCodes = CountryCodes.Algeria
```